# Selenium Grid 2 set up on Windows

Tags: selenium-webdriver, selenium-grid

I am setting up Selenium Grid 2 (selenium-server-standalone-2.1.0) on Windows 7 (I have also tried Windows Server 2008) both 64 bit. I test the WebDriver locally and all is well.

I launch the hub with:

java -jar selenium-server-standalone-2.1.0.jar -role hub

Adding a webDriver node for FireFox works, but anything else such as Google Chrome throws an IllegalOperation Exception.

For example:

I try adding a node for Chrome:

java -jar selenium-server-standalone-2.1.0.jar -role webDriver -hub  http://127.0.0.1:4444 -browser browserName=chrome platform=windows version=12 -port 5556

This shows as a node on the hub when you go to http://localhost:4444/grid/console

I add code to call the webDriver such as:

```
            DesiredCapabilities capability = new DesiredCapabilities();
            capability.SetCapability(CapabilityType.Platform, "windows");
            capability.SetCapability(CapabilityType.Version, "12");
            capability.SetCapability(CapabilityType.BrowserName, "chrome");

            IWebDriver driver = new RemoteWebDriver(new Uri("http://127.0.0.1:4444/wd/hub"), capability);
```

I get an exception almost immediately:

{"cannot find : {platform=windows, browserName=chrome, version=12}"}

It seems as if the node isn't even being found. I am new to this is it something I have missed in the set up? (internet explorer does the same and changing versions doesn't seem to help).

I have searched for hours and hours but nothing that matches the exception seems as generic as my problem.

Comment: Please include the config output as the grid sees it.  You can get this by clicking the "View Config" link in the Web console.  The following link should also have the data: http://127.0.0.1:4444/grid/console?config=true&configDebug=true

Comment: Thanks I have figured it out. I can see in the config the lines throwOnCapabilityNotPresent : true
capabilityMatcher : org.openqa.grid.internal.utils.DefaultCapabilityMatcher, the error is thrown because there is no matching capability. Cheers for pointing me in the right direction.

Answer (score 2):

The IllegalOperation Exception {"cannot find : {platform=windows, browserName... is caused by there being no matching capability (it never gets as far as a Node).

If I use a config file when I launch the node that explicitly states the platform and browser such as:

```
{
"capabilities":
        [
                {
                        "browserName":"firefox",
                        "maxInstances":1
                },
                {
                        "browserName":"chrome",
            "platform":"WINDOWS",
                        "maxInstances":1
                },
                {
                        "browserName":"internet explorer",
                        "version":"9",
                        "platform":"WINDOWS",
                        "maxInstances":1
                }
        ],
"configuration":
        {
                "cleanUpCycle":2000,
                "timeout":30000,
                "proxy":"org.openqa.grid.selenium.proxy.WebDriverRemoteProxy",
                "maxSession":5,
                "url":"http://[myIP]/wd/hub",

        }
}
```

and launch the hub with this line:
java -jar selenium-server-standalone-2.2.0.jar -role webdriver -nodeConfig myconfig.json -hub http://[myIP]:4444/grid/register

and create the capabilities like so:

```
DesiredCapabilities capability = new DesiredCapabilities();
capability.SetCapability(CapabilityType.Platform, "WINDOWS");
capability.SetCapability(CapabilityType.BrowserName, "internet explorer");
```

Then the test works (you have to set all Zones in IE to protected by the way).
N.B. I did notice that windows is UPPERCASE as in WINDOWS or you get an error.

Comment: can you give an example. I get error when running hub with your command

Answer (score 2):

The docs do actually document this but in an unclear way.

```
java -jar selenium-server-standalone-2.1.0.jar -role webDriver -hub http://127.0.0.1:4444 -browser browserName=chrome platform=windows version=12 -port 5556
```

Needs to be:

```
java -Dwebdriver.chrome.driver="C:\Users\Mike\Documents\Java Libraries\Selenium\chromedriver\chromedriver.exe" -jar selenium-server-standalone-2.1.0.jar -role webDriver -hub http://127.0.0.1:4444/grid/register -browser "browserName=chrome,platform=WINDOWS,version=12" -port 5556
```

You are missing `grid/register` from the hub URL. On top of this, if you are passing multiple arguments to `-browser` they need to be enclosed in quotes and separated by commas without spaces. You also need to pass in the `webdriver.chrome.driver` property in a similar way to how I did it.

You can check that it has successfully registered by going to your browser and hitting:

```
http://localhost:4444/grid/console
```

And as a sidenote, this is another way you could declare the desired capabilities:

```
DesiredCapabilities dc = DesiredCapabilities.chrome();
dc.setVersion("12");
dc.setPlatform(Platform.WINDOWS);
```

Comment: can the path map to Chrome.exe, or does it have to be the ChromeDriver?

Comment: @Tyler: It must be to `ChromeDriver`

Answer (score 1):

```
Lets consider Hub running on Machine-A whose IPAddress is = 192.168.10.10 default port no. 4444.
Lets Node running on Machine-B whose IPAddress is = 192.168.10.20.
Lets consider operating System on HUB and Node is installed on drive C:\ (C-Drive). 
create a folder named selenium on c:\ as c:\selenium.
keep binaries of IExplorer.exe, chromeDriver.exe and Selenium-Standalone-server2.10.0.jar. (on both machine A and B).

configuring HUB on Machine-A
1- open Command prompt 
2- go to folder selenium using 
         i type cd\ then enter
         ii  type c:  then enter
         iii c:> cd selenium then enter
3- java -jar selenium-server-standalone-2.20.0.jar -role hub

Configuring NOde on Machine - B
1- open Command prompt 
2- go to folder selenium using 
         i type cd\ then enter
         ii  type c:  then enter
         iii c:> cd selenium then enter
3- java -jar selenium-server-standalone-2.20.0.jar -role node -hub http://192.168.10.10:4444/grid/register  -port 5560 -browser  browserName=chrome,maxInstance=4,platform=WIN8_1 -Dwebdriver.ie.driver=c:\selenium\ChromeDriver.exe

your node will get register with Hub on port 5560.

Test Case will become as- 

package testCase;

import static org.junit.Assert.*;

import java.net.URL;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

import org.junit.After;
import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.DesiredCapabilities;
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver;

public class Avinash_Google_Chrome 
{

    WebDriver driver;
    String baseUrl , nodeUrl;

    @Before
    public void setUp() throws Exception 
    {
        nodeUrl = "http://192.168.10.20:5560/wd/hub"; //Machine-A IPAdress  
                                                     with Port No.          

        DesiredCapabilities capability = DesiredCapabilities.chrome();

        driver = new RemoteWebDriver(new URL(nodeUrl),capability);
        driver.manage().window().maximize();
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(2, TimeUnit.MINUTES);
    }

    @After
    public void tearDown() throws Exception 
    {
        driver.quit();
    }

    @Test
    public void test() throws InterruptedException
    {

        driver.get("https://www.google.co.in");     
        Thread.sleep(3000);     
        driver.findElement(By.linkText("Gmail")).click();
        Thread.sleep(3000); 
        driver.findElement(By.id("Email")).sendKeys("aavinashpande@gmail.com");

        driver.findElement(By.id("Passwd")).sendKeys("********");

        driver.findElement(By.id("signIn")).click();

        Thread.sleep(6000);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to lower the conditions about the chrome version and the operating system:

Your code to register the node would be the following

```
java -jar selenium-server-standalone-2.1.0.jar -role webDriver -hub http://127.0.0.1:4444 -browser browserName=chrome -port 5556
```

And to create your browser:

```
DesiredCapabilities capability = new DesiredCapabilities();
capability.SetCapability(CapabilityType.BrowserName, "chrome");
```

or

```
DesiredCapabilities capability = DesiredCapabilities.chrome();
```

It can be that your Chrome updated without you noticing or that the version number "12" is not perfectly fitting to your installed version. 
If it runs under these conditions, try to add the "Platform=WINDOWS" and the "Version" CapabilityTypes with new combinations.

Comment: This only obscures what he's done wrong. You've missed out on the main reasons why his command for instantiating the node is incorrect and your command will also not work.

Answer (score 0):

You can set

```
driver.quit();
```

at the end of your script